# How is code synchronized with graphics?

Tags: graphics

I cannot figure out how graphics is linked with code just like it is done in games and operating systems like Windows, OS X,etc. How is it done?Is the code executed via the graphics or the graphics is executed through the code?

Answer (score 1):

The system sends a frame synch interrupt or message. The code is written so that it does a chunk of work in slightly under a frame, and it then has a new frame to present to the viewer when the request comes along.

So if a spaceship is moving, the program calculates its velocity in pixels per 1/60 second. Then it adds that amount to its position, and redraws it on the new frame.